# r: groupby result different from result manually counted in view(dataframe)

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataset like this

```
ID               Date       County
gvxyz-00        7/27/23     x   
gv23xyz-00      7/27/23     x
gv230xyz-00     7/27/23     y
```

I'm using groupby() and count() to count how many observations happened in each day in seperate counties. so the tibble result should be

```
county date       n
x      2023-7-27  2
y      2023-7-27  1
```

Yet the results of n from my tibbles don't match what I got after counting when I view the dataset. Tibble results are significantly larger than my manual counts. I don't know where did it go wrong, like is it my View() not showing dataset fully or tibble not working, which I highly doubt. I didn't even know how to start searching for this question because it seems highly in odd to me. Any help is super appreciated.

my code is

```
df %>%
  group_by(county, date)  %>%
  count(nrow(df$date)) %>% 
  print(n = Inf) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I re-subset my dataset and reworked it. Still mismatching.

Answer (score 0):

With `count` you do not need to use `group_by`. `count` is equivalent to `group_by(xyz) %>% summarise(n = n())`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(County, Date)
```

```
  County    Date n
1      x 7/27/23 2
2      y 7/27/23 1
```